# Event Handler/Register Service without parameter?

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling, parameter-passing

We have a program that I have been asked to implement a new module into. The new module has a ADK so it should be easy. However, the demo code is written in C# (and runs on WPF).

My question is about an Event Handler. In the C# code, this is the Event Handler:

```
// handle dispatch base events
void EventHandler_DSPBASE(EventBase e)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceEvent serviceEvent = e as ServiceEvent;
        if (serviceEvent == null)
            return;

        // more code here
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // catch exceptions here
    }
}
```

On Initialized the EventHandler is set with this:

```
// register dispatch handler
ServiceBase servicebase = _oModule.GetService(ServiceType.DSPBASE);
if (servicebase != null)
{
    // handle data received from the dispatch base component
    servicebase.Register(EventHandler_DSPBASE);
    servicebase.SetDispatchBaseOption(12500, DispatchBase.ROUTE_DATA_RECEIVED);
}
```

Using VS 2015 I can run the demo code with no problems. When I translate this to VB.NET I get an error because the Event Handler requires the parameter (EventBase e). So in the Initialized section, this VB.NET code won't run.

```
Dim servicebase As ServiceBase = _oModule.GetService(ServiceType.DSPBASE)
If servicebase IsNot Nothing Then
    ' handle data received from the dispatch base component
    servicebase.Register(EventHandler_DSPBASE)  ' <- error here - red squiggly line in parenthesis
    servicebase.SetDispatchBaseOption(12500, DispatchBase.ROUTE_DATA_RECEIVED)
End If
```

Is there a reason that this code will run through C# but not through VB.NET? And is there a way I can set that Handler without passing the argument that the procedure requires in VB.NET?

Comment: What does the error actually say?  Try using [AddressOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator) like this: `servicebase.Register(AddressOf EventHandler_DSPBASE)`.

Comment: The error message is "Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Private Sub EventHandler_DSPBASE(EventBase e)'.

Comment: Sorry, hit Enter by mistake. Also, adding in the AddressOf resulted in the same message. It changed it to servicebase.Register(AddressOf (EventHandler_DSPBASE())) but still with the red line underneath.

Comment: It may require a Delegate to be created manually and passed in.  Type in ".Register" and then type in that first Left Parenthesis so you can see what it expects as a parameter to be passed in.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - you lost me at Delegate :) I typed in what you wrote and the pop-up looks like a standard list of stuff (not sure what to call it). I uploaded a screenshot for illustration. Hopefully this will work: [link](https://postimg.org/image/slytpha61/)

Comment: You've got an extra `.` period in there.  Type the left parenthesis directly after that last `r` and it should give a signature for the `Register()` method only.

Comment: Removing the extra period gave me the same pop up items. I also tried duplicating the Handler and removing the parameter but that gave me an error message of doesn't return a value.

Comment: To be of any help I need to know the signature of that method.  Can you provide any documentation for that method, or a link to docs?

Comment: @Idle_Mind - I apologize for not getting back sooner. I ended up going on the road for some onsite work. I don't know what I did wrong (fat-fingered typo or something) but the AddressOf did fix the issue. I think initially I did servicebase.Register(AddressOf(EventHandler_DSPBase)) when what fixed it was servicebase.Register(AddressOf EventHandler_DSPBASE). That space after AddressOf seems to have fixed it. Thank you for the help. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yay!  Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what I did wrong (fat-fingered typo or something) but the
>   AddressOf did fix the issue.

Use [AddressOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator) like this:

```
servicebase.Register(AddressOf EventHandler_DSPBASE)
```